# Palindrome Program is running but is giving an error message

Tags: java, palindrome

This program is suppose to tell whether or not a word is a palindrome (same word forward and backward). I'm having trouble figuring out why my computer will run this program while also having an error message to go with it. Can someone please explain?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out
of range:
```

code

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter word here: ");
        String a = StdIn.readLine();

        for(int i = a.length() - 1 ; i >= 0; ++i)
        {
            if (a.charAt(i) != a.charAt(a.length() - i)) System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
            else System.out.println("Palindrome");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop iteration variable i is being incremented in the wrong direction. You should have

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
```

OR

```
for(int i = a.length() - 1 ; i >= 0; --i)
```

You also need to change

```
a.charAt(a.length() - i))
```

to

```
a.charAt((a.length() - 1) - i)
```

because charAt uses a zero based index, like all other string manipulation methods.

Comment: FYI - in my experience the first suggestion would be better because it is unusual to have a for loop where the variable is decremented.

Comment: it's not right, will throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` here: `a.charAt(a.length() - i))`

Answer (score 0):

Decrement variable i instead of incrementing it in the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop should be decrementing `i` not increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the counter `i`, but you should be decrementing it, because you start at `i = a.length() - 1`. This is also what the exception is trying to tell you. Furthermore, you're comparing all the characters of the string twice!

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops when exception is thrown.
You have several mistakes so I decided to rewrite your code. Call this method from main:

```
  static void isPalindrome(String s) {
        boolean res = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i)) {
                res = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res ? "Palindrome" : "Not s Palindrome");
    }
```

Comment: This helped a lot the only thing I added was for it to be able to recognize if a letter was capitalized. Thanks for the help!